# How to open Telegram desktop source in Qt?

Tags: qt, telegram

I'm trying to open the source of Telegram (desktop version) in Qt but I can't find any .pro file.

Comment: this file: https://github.com/Kaffeine/telegram-qt/blob/master/telegram-qt.pro?

Comment: Qt Creator also supports cmake files.